# Trying to make the dialog box appear

Tags: android

So I was trying my hands on making a dialog box appear when the user exit the app and it will ask the question Are you sure you want to exit? The app exit but it doesn't show the dialog box.

Here is my code

```
public void exit(View view) {

        //  showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG1);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", null);   
    }             
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Register.this.finish();
//                  builder.show();

 }
           };
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

Place this on your exit function:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit");

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    // Setting positive button click action
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         Register.this.finish(); 
    }
});

// Creating and then showing AlertDialog
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Thank You so much! for my first question I'm surprised how awesome this place is. But could you explain what i was doing wrong? i like to learn

Comment: You are welcome. Bro you only set builder no related code for AlertyDialog showing. I add that and you also set positive button clicklistener in wrong way. I also correct that.

Comment: I also add comments on that lines. You can check that. Do not forget to accept/tick my answer @HarshJoshi :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will check for the back button press, prior to creating the messagebox.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Handle the back button
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //Ask the user if they want to quit
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle(R.string.quit)
            .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Stop the activity
                    YourClass.this.finish();    
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
            .show();

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```